# “We are so good swimmer.” or “We are so good swimmers.”

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> “The enemies devise a plot to drown us; o my friend, tell them that we are so good swimmer.”

While writing a poetry in my native Urdu language, I thought to translate the above couplet into English. If we say “we are so good swimmer” is all grammatically fine in my mother tongue. Is it fine in also English, or should we pluralise ‘swimmer’?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *swimmers* should be plural to go with *we.* It would be more idiomatic to say *such good swimmers.*

Comment: I know that We is a plural term of I, but the WordWeb dictionary says ‘we’ is also used in informal writing as I.

Comment: _We_ can be used to refer to one person only in _very formal_ contexts. People joke about monarchs calling themselves _we_, but in fact they only do so when speaking in their official capacity. The writer of a textbook may say 'In the next chapter we shall discuss...'